# How to move where a branch originates from

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, git-workflow

I feel like I’m missing something basic with Git but is there a way to move where a branch originates from? I’m running into a scenario very often where I create a feature branch off of master, work on it for a few days, then went I push it I need to make sure that any changes that were added to master need to be merged/rebased onto my branch. This seems to make my branch very messy. I’d imagine I could simply change where the branch originates from to where master currently is now as if I just made the branch in the first place (but obviously, I’d need to handle any conflicts that arise). Is there a way to do this or some other process to keep my branch clean?

What I’m hoping for is being able switch from:

```
a--b--d--f
    \
     c--e--g
```

to

```
a--b--d--f
          \
           c--e--g
```

Edit:
Recently, to emulate this, I've been working off of temporary branches, when my work is complete I will create a new branch, and move all commits to that and recommit them all and push. This doesn't work very well if the pull-request reviews take a while. I've also recently tried doing a `git pull --rebase upstream master` then merging master into the branch. That added tons of other peoples commits to my branch. I'm thinking that the merge screwed things up, but I didn't realize before I pushed and checked the pull-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing *is* rebasing. You're just doing it in the wrong direction. Let's say `master` points to commit `f` and `your-branch` points to `g`.

```
a---b---d---f  ← master
     \
      c---e---g  ← your-branch
```

To take your branch and make it "start" at the commit `f`, you have to rebase `your-branch` on `master`. The corresponding command is:

```
git rebase master your-branch
```

Git will first check out the branch you specified in as your second argument (here `your-branch`). Thus, you can omit the second argument if you already have that branch checked out.

The first argument will be used to determine the base commit, which is `b` in this example. Git will use the first common ancestor between the branch you provided and your currently checked out branch.

Unless you specified `--onto`, Git will use the first argument again to determine the new base. In this case, that's the commit `f`. The result is:

```
a---b---d---f  ← master
             \
              c'--e'--g' ← your-branch
```

Just keep in mind that the commit hashes will change, since you essentially have new commits. I marked the new commits with a prime (`'`).

---

> I've also recently tried doing a `git pull --rebase upstream master` then merging master into the branch.

You don't want to merge `master` into your branch after rebasing on it. Rebasing does exactly what you described, and you don't need additional steps.